# How to handle host name during Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am making an ajax call:

```
var hostUrl = location.hostname;
     $.getJSON(hostUrl + "/DataMatrix/ItemTypeList/" + $("#filter > option:selected").attr("value"),
                function (dataValue) {
```

This is what I get in my network tab:

```
http://localhost:50020/localhost/DataMatrix/ItemTypeList/5001
```

Localhost gets appended on top of local host, however in production it works fine as url formed is (xyz: host placeholder).

```
 xyz/DataMatrix/ItemTypeList/5001
```

Once I remove host url then it works great in local too, but fail in production:

```
 $.getJSON("/DataMatrix/ItemTypeList/" + $("#filter > option:selected").attr("value"),
                    function (dataValue) {
```

How to handle such scenario during development so that I don't have to change the string when I am handing over the files to deployment team.

Comment: Can you just remove the leading "/" (i.e. ` $.getJSON("DataMatrix/ItemTypeList/"` ?

Comment: Yeah it works in local machine but fails in prod , because asp.net MVC cannot figure out the url.

Comment: create a virtual host when working in localhost and change your url to "yourproductionurl.com.local" something like that

Comment: Use the @Url.Action helper to generate the link to the action instead of specifying it by hand (assuming the target is an MVC controller action)

Comment: @ADyson: Yes by removing leading "/" it works in both local and prod! Whats the reasoning?

Comment: @ADyson :And my reply after your first comment was intended to some other comment where somebody suggested to remove host url, that comment is not there any more, making it look like that I have replied to you, but in fact I was working on remote server to make the changes you suggested.

Comment: @Liliput see my answer below

Comment: Set a base url variable based on environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove the leading "/" ie:

```
$.getJSON("DataMatrix/ItemTypeList/" ...
```

This is because the the browser will automatically interpret the URL as being relative to the current host (e.g. "http://localhost:50020/" or "https://myhost.com/") and prepend that to your stated URL.

So if you put "DataMatrix/ItemTypeList" in your URL when deployed on "https://myhost.com", the ajax call will automatically make the call to "https://myhost.com/DataMatrix/ItemTypeList".